# Array of a type which is an array of another type - C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have this code:

```
typedef struct Table* TableP;

typedef struct DataPointer
{
    void* dataP;
    void* key;
}DataPointer;

typedef struct HashTableSet
{
    DataPointer *hashSet[2];
}HashTableSet;

typedef struct Table
{
    int size, d;
    HashTableSet *hashTableSet;
}Table;

void nullTable(size_t)
{
    TableP myTable = (Table*)malloc(size_t*sizeof(HashTableSet)*sizeof(DataPointer);
    Table table = *tableP;
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < tableP->size; i++)
    {
        int j = 0;
        for (; j < MAX_ROW_ELEMENTS ; ++j)
        {
            DataPointer data;
            DataPointer *dataP = &data;
            data.key = NULL;
            data.dataP = NULL;
            table[i][j] = data;
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to have Table as an array of HashTableSet, and HashTableSet an array of DataPointer, and in the null function i am trying to create all spots in the table to be initialized to NULL (atlist the pointers). But i get this error message:

```
 error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
         table[i][j] = data;
```

So what am i doing wrong? I guess i need some pointer to pointer action but i am not sure how to do it in a case that i have a 2Dimentional array with different types in each dimension.

Comment: The message is correct - `table` is neither an array nor a pointer.

Comment: Please don't cast the return of `malloc` & co in C. using `typedef` to obscure the fact that you're dealing with pointers is also considered to be bad style in most cases. Another thing: inside `nullTable`, you're allocating memory, not returning anything, and never `free`'ing the memory. You're leaking memory in other words

Comment: Use table variable as a double pointer.

Comment: This `void nullTable(size_t)` misses the variable name. `size_t` is just a type.

Comment: Looking at the code a bit closer, you don't seem to understand how pointers actually work: `table` isn't a pointer, it's a struct. The memory you've allocated doesn't exactly make sense (in terms of size, you actually want to allocate `sizeof(Table)`, and then allocate memory for the `hashTableSet` member separately. At no point does `table[i][j]` make sense. The offset of the first member of a struct is guaranteed to be 0, but the first member of `table` is an `int`, which you're accessing as an array of sorts. That will never, ever work

Comment: Here "*and HashTableSet an array of DataPointer*" the verb is missing, which I feel is essential to understand what you are after.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I do lack understanding and trying to learn by this example. Should Table hold **HashTableSet?

Comment: Alright, i think i understood a little. I am now trying something closer to: table.hashTableSet->hashSet[j] instead of table[i][j].